# Word that I kept hearing at the end of a sentence

Tags: word-requests

I don't know any Chinese, but I went to a kind of sales pitch by a Chinese salesman. He kept saying a word at the end of some sentences. The best I could think of the English pronunciation would be div-e-day. It was always in the form of a question, so I think it might be something to the effect of "am I right" in English.  Any guesses?

Comment: My guess it's 对不对. It's a rhetorical question - "am I not right".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "word" you are asking about is not one word but two: "对不对" 
对： Right
不对： Wrong
So he is asking you that: Is it correct or not? But actually meaning for this is trying to convince people like "Don't you think what i said is very reasonable? Yes, I am right!"

The Pinyin for these words: DUI 对, BU 不， DUI 对

Comment: Great thank you! Thats what I figured it might be.